# Accessing hidden element value (javascript)

Tags: javascript

Pls have a look at the following code.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

function apps(){

var app= new Array(8);

   for (var i=0;i<8;i++)
   {

    app[i]= ....;
   }
                }
</script>

<input type="hidden" name="NEW" value= ? >

< ....button label="Submit" OnClick='apps();return false;'/>
```

Here the apps() method gets executed on clicking the Submit button.
I want to access the value of app (Array) by use of a hidden element. Pls let me know what code I should write for this purpose.

Comment: Format your code please.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />
document.write(document.getElementsByName('foo')[0].value);
```

output is "bar". getElementsByName returns an array of matching form elements with the name supplied. the `[0]` grabs the first match, and `.value` retrieves the value.

Comment: Thanks Brad.I understood your code but would the same concept work for my code, as my variable in within a script? Just asking. I'm not that familiar with Js :)

Comment: @unos: Where does the 8 come from? Do you have 8 hidden elements you want to access/assign? You can use variables in the `getElementsByName` just by doing: `var i = 1; var j = document.getElementsByName('element'+i)[0];` which matches `<input type="hidden" name="element1" />` That make sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) as well.

```
<input id="foo-hidden" type="hidden" name="foo" value="bar" />

<script type="text/javascript">
   function apps() {
     var app= new Array(8);
     for (var i=0; i < 8; i++) {
        app[i]= $('#foo-hidden').val();
     }
   }
</script>
```